# Alternative of Microsoft silverlight on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I've tried installing Moonlight and failed miserably and moonlight is not actively developed.so i was hoping you guys could help me out here with another alternative.

The browser i'm currently using is google chrome, if that helps and i'm running Ubuntu 14.04. 
Thank you

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't use Silverlight anymore. I watch Netflix videos on Google Chrome without Silverlight. Why do you need Silverlight? http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2383624/google-will-kill-microsoft-silverlight-in-chrome-by-disabling-npapi-plug-in

Answer (score 3):

install pipelight instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Comment: also you can add netflix desktop app ppa...let me know if the first answer doesn't get it working

Answer (score 0):

Install pipelight instead (revisited):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Restart Firefox, Chromium or whatever...
Then:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

To enable the plugin (in Firefox):

```
about:addons
```

or

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```