# Can't install silverlight/pipelight

Tags: software-installation, pipelight, moonlight

For netflix, silverlight or pipelight is needed. I've looked at several different places, such as these sites:

- [Alternative of Microsoft silverlight on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611505/alternative-of-microsoft-silverlight-on-ubuntu)
- [How to install Microsoft Silverlight on Mozilla Firefox browser in an easiest and reliable way that runs on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit operating system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605460/how-to-install-microsoft-silverlight-on-mozilla-firefox-browser-in-an-easiest-an)
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-enable-silverlight-watch-netflix-linux/

I've tried running all of the code in the terminal, and it always says something like no installation candidate. Does anyone know how to actually install it?

Comment: "For netflix, silverlight or pipelight is needed" this assumption is incorrect in first place. Check the answer. You only need chrome even if you don't want to use firefox

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pipelight.  Use the method explained in the answer to this question: [Now that I have Firefox 49, how do I watch Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-how-do-i-watch-netflix)